# Calculate expected heterozygocity using Wright's F statistics (here, FIS)

Tags: population-genetics, hardy-weinberg, fst

I try to better understand Wright's F statistics. In general, there are many derivations and many interpretations, and in books, the parameters are called differently, that's why I am struggling.

More specifically, I want to understand how the inbreeding coefficient ($F_{IS}$) can be used to calculate the expected heterozygosity $H_e$.

The following formula makes sense to me:

$H_e=2pq(1-F_{IS})$,
$F_{IS}$ is the fraction of a population where the alleles at a given locus are Identical By Descent (IBD), i.e. homozygous. For the remaining fraction ($1-F_{IS}$), the Hardy-Weinberg principle applies and the frequency of heterozygotes is $2pq$.

However, in the slides my professor gave me, the parameter $F_t$, sometimes called only $F$, is used. He called this the *fixation index* (which, according to other definitions, would be $F_{ST}$), but since he used it as the probability for an allele to be IBD, I assume this might be what others called *inbreeding coefficient* $F_{IS}$ (that is a least a common definition I found in multiple books). But in the book "[A Primer of Population Genetics and Genomics](https://academic.oup.com/book/41658)", the same definition is used, i.e. $F_t=F_{ST}=$ the probability to be IBD due to *remote* inbreeding.

Could somebody help me with my confusion?

Anyways, in the lectures, this formula is given to calculate the expected heterozygosity:

$H_e=1-F_{t}$,
where $F_t$ might be $F_{ST}$ or $F_{IS}$, see above

Could somebody help me understand if these formulas mean the same (under different assumptions of cause) or why both formulas exist?